# Watch face preview dependent by the screen form

Tags: wear-os

Is there a way to specify the preview of my watch face, which appears on the watch face selection screen, to be different for round and square screens?

It is a little weird to see round watch face preview on square screen and square preview on round screen. The watch face shows the proper layout depending by the screen form factor, but I didn't find a way to specify different preview depending by the screen form in the following tag.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview" android:resource="@drawable/preview" />
```

I know the watch face API is not yet released, but I am asking is there a way with the available API to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are asking is no longer supported.
You can find relevant information including answers to your problem here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html